Is it haram to make anime facts youtube channel
I have anime facts channel which contains anime related facts.I try my best to make it halal like i don't show any female character and don't use bad words and don't add music and etc. But is it ok to do that?Because many scholars say that the video which contain haram things then it is haram other wise not.so what can i do?
Jazakallah in advance.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.

Can anyone send this msg to scholr or anyone can give answer
